# Linear Regression quadratic terms

Tags: statistics, terminology, regression, linear-regression

I have a hard time understanding the term 'linear regression'. For what I know, linear means polynomial of degree 1. But then, I found that in one of my lectures, the lecturers are saying that this regression is a linear regression: $$Y_i=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x_i +\alpha_2 x_i^2$$

How is this a linear regression when it has quadratic terms in it? Does it not make it a non-linear regression? However when there is a quadratic curve as the regression, it is called a non-linear regression. Which is right?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/what-does-linear-stand-for-in-linear-regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data $(x_i,y_i)$ are given, so although it looks like you have a quadratic because of the $x_i^2$, in fact this is just a constant. You're solving for $\alpha_0, \alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, and the equation is linear in these terms.

Comment: ooooh I see then. Also, then what is a non linear regression?

Comment: @Skipe Non-linear regression could involve mixing the $\alpha$ terms with each other, or using them inside other functions. For instance, $Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_i + \alpha_2(1-\alpha_0)x_i^2$, or $Y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \cos(\alpha_2 x + \alpha_3)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh it does. So what is meant by linear in this case is the $\alpha$'s right? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Skipe That's right! Glad to help.